# Unable to run on simulator with Xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

[image: Xcode error]

I am unable to run on simulator with XCode 9. I am getting this error.

Currently I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: check you OS is compatible with xcode 9.0. Or you have to update for it.

Comment: Xcode 9 requires macOS 10.12.6 or later.  Are you *sure* you are on 10.12.6?  If so, please take a sysdiagnose and file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com.  If you do so, please report back the radar number here, so I can check it out.

Comment: radar # 34487654 @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like you have an installation problem.  Simulator.app cannot find SimulatorKit.framework... How did you install Xcode 9?

Comment: took it through airdrop! @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia

Answer (score 1):

You mention you took it through airdrop. 
You must move the xcode.app to applications folder, then do this:

`sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`

You must make the gatekeeper let your xcode and simulator app to continue on using it without verifying it.

Comment: I am not sure about this. I have reinstalled my Xcode from official Apple software library.