# iOS simulator does not display anything

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I run the app as usual in Xcode 9.0.1 and Simulator 10.0 but the iOS simulator does not display anything. I have attached the image of the simulator below. I already tried to Erase all Content and Settings but it did not help. This is the first time that I've encountered something like this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does it display iOS desktop like that as well? Looks like a simulator bug.

Comment: No, it does not display the iOS home screen or anything.

Comment: Can you file a bug report and attach `sudo sysdiagnose -q` and `xcrun simctl diagnose` output? This looks like corruption due to mis-alignment, probably a GPU bug. You can try `defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Thanks, russbishop, for the detailed info. I will file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a problem; it definitely looks like the simulator is corrupted. First, try a different simulator. You're using "iPhone 8 Plus - iOS 11.0" currently. Try a different one. They're all separate images. If that's the problem, you can delete that simulator and reinstall it. In Xcode:

- Window>Devices & Simulators
- Simulators
- Delete by right-clicking and selecting Delete. Install by pressing + at the bottom left.

If that doesn't address it, I would reinstall Xcode. This has to be corruption in either the simulator itself or one of the simulator images.

Comment: Thanks, Rob for the answer. I did try with a different simulator but the same issue repeated. I'll try reinstalling the Xcode and see if that helps.

Comment: I did try a bunch of solutions and I'm not sure which one worked :D. I'll accept your answer and provide a link to the other solution which I referred as well. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832062/5370404

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try clean your build and derived data.
2. If above won't work you can try quitting Xcode and Simulator and restart it again.

Comment: Thanks, Chetan. I did try both of the suggestions but still the same issue.

Comment: Have you downloaded this Xcode or took it from somewhere else? If you have not downloaded then their might be a chance that its simulator files got corrupted while initialising. I had similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239122/unable-to-run-on-simulator-with-xcode-9-0

Comment: Hi Chetan, I had downloaded Xcode from the official app store.